# Unexpected (random) execution order using tf.control_dependencies (tensorflow v1)

Tags: tensorflow, graph, dependencies, execution, order-of-execution

When I run the following code (tf v1.12.0), I get either 6.0 (x->mul->ident), 7.0 (x->mul->add->ident, or 9.0 (x->add->mul->ident).

Could someone please explain why the order of execution of the ops is not controlled by the tf.control_dependencies? I would think that at least add_op would be executed before anything within the control context is even considered.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

x=tf.Variable(2.0)
add_op = tf.assign_add(x, 1)
mul_op = tf.assign(x, 3*x)

with tf.control_dependencies([add_op]):
    out_op = tf.identity(mul_op)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run([out_op]))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `mul_op` does not depend on `add_op`. Rather the `out_op` is dependent on both `mul_op` (as an explicit input) and `add_op` as a control dependency. In TensorFlow 1.x (and in TensorFlow 2.x inside a `tf.Graph` context), the order of the operations *in Python* does not affect the order of operations *in the TensorFlow runtime*.

To force deterministic behavior for the example above, there are a few options.

1. Construct the `mul_op` inside a `tf.control_dependencies` context using the `add_op`:

```py
add_op = tf.assign_add(x, 1)
with tf.control_dependencies([add_op]):
  mul_op = tf.assign(x, 3 * x)
```

2. Have `mul_op` take the output of the addition (`add_op`) as an input.

```py
add_op = tf.assign_add(x, 1)
mul_op = tf.assign(x, 3 * add_op)
```

3. Remove the control dependency from the identity op and call sess.run() on `out_op` and `add_op` explicitly.

```py
x=tf.Variable(2.0)
add_op = tf.assign_add(x, 1)
mul_op = tf.assign(x, 3*x)
out_op = tf.identity(mul_op)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(add_op)
    print(sess.run(out_op))
```

These always return `9.0`.

To dig *really* deep and see what the dependencies in the graph are, you could try:

```
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
```

an see what the `input` values to each node in the graph are.

Comment: thanks for the answer! To clarify, does that mean that there is no set execution order between mul_op and add_op (aside from them both having to execute before the out_op)? I see how that would explain the "7" and "9" outputs, but how about the "6"? In that case it seems that the out_op executes before the add_op

Comment: Updated the answer to specify some more options, but yes: the order of operations in the Python source code does *not* affect the order of operations executed by TensorFlow. When variable `x` is the input to an operation, it implicitly is calling `x.read_value()`. It is possible the variable read for `mul_op` (which is executed because `out_op` depends on it _directly) happens *before* `add_op` is executed (which `out_op` depends on via the control dep), resulting in the assignment of `2.0 * 3`. This could be thought of as a read-write race condition due to the lack of dependencies.